# How to add source/Javadoc for ATSL and Espresso in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-source, android-espresso, android-testing

I am adding Android testing support library (ATSL) and espresso dependencies like below. But Android studio is not showing the Javadoc or source code for the library and is just showing a decompiled version of methods and classes

```
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

I just noticed that for older versions of support testing library, sources are still being downloaded and shown.